# Numbers of subsets with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We have a class of 30 students.

1. In how many ways can we choose a group of 5 students (order does not matter)?
2. In how many ways can we split the class in 7 unordered groups?
3. We want to split the class into five teams (a, b, c, d, e). every team has the same number of students?

First question I solved this with combination formula $\binom{30}{5}$
The second I think this can be solved with stirlink 2nd kind number $S(30,7)$, am I right??
And the last one, it's hard for me to say that this is the correct method.
I chose 6 students first in $\binom{30}{6}$ ways, then we have 24 students left. I chose again 6 students in $\binom{24}{6}$ ways and so on.
So my final answer would be $\binom{30}{6}\ast \binom{24}{6}\ast \binom{18}{6}\ast\binom{12}{6}\ast \binom{6}{6}$. Is that a good solve?

Comment: Did you mean teams of five or teams of six?

Comment: there are 5 teams, so yes, my mistake.

Comment: Assuming $a, b, c, d, e$ are labels for the teams, all your answers are correct.  If the teams were not labeled, you would have to divide your answer to the last question by $5!$.  Welcome to MathSE.

Comment: thanks for answering me!